# How to solve a complicated ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

The equation is
$$
f^{\prime}(x) = \gamma \frac{f(x)+f^2(x)}{\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}\right)}
$$
with the initial condition $f(0)$, where $x\geq 0$ and $f(0)\geq0$.

The solution is
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{-1+\exp\sqrt{2\gamma x + \log\left(\frac{f(0)+1}{f(0)}\right)^2}}$$

I think the ODE can be solved by separating the variables
$$
\int_{0}^{f(x)} \frac{\log\left(\frac{f(z)}{1+f(z)}\right)}{f(z)+f^2(z)} df = \int_{0}^{x} \gamma dz
$$
The right-hand size is easy. I do not know how to solve the integration of the left-hand side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Your method so far is correct. What you are asking for is the integral
$$\int \frac{\log\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)}{y+y^2}~dy.$$
The integral at first looks deceptively hard to solve but it is actually very easy if you notice it is of the form
$$\int g(y)g'(y)~dy$$
for $g(y)=\log\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. As regards the integral on the left, note that
$$\int \frac{1}{f(z)+f^2(z)} df =
\int \left(\frac{1}{f(z)}-\frac{1}{1+f(z)}\right) df =\log\left(\frac{f(z)}{1+f(z)}\right)+c.$$
Can you take it from here?